# Join two strings in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have two strings in Terraform:

```
"1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2"

"3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4"
```

How do I get

```
"1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4"
```

Seems very trivial, but could not find a function/workaround for it.

Comment: Where do the strings come from? Are they variables? Do they come from the output of a resource or module? Have you tried interpolating them together?

Comment: It's an output like this:

"${join(",", aws_instance.my_instance.*.public_ip)}"

Comment: And the second string is from another resource? Then you should just be able to put them next to each other (with a comma to separate them) like this: `"${join(",", aws_instance.my_instance.*.public_ip)},${join(",", aws_instance.my_instance2.*.public_ip)}"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[string templates](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#string-templates) and [join](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/join.html) are the immediate solutions I reach for:

```
locals {
  string1 = "1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2"

  string2 = "3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4"

  strings_join = join(",", [local.string1, local.string2])

  strings_template = "${local.string1},${local.string2}"
}
```